# dev environment returns blank page

Tags: php, symfony

I'm currently working on with a Symfony project (const VERSION ='2.5.0') and I'm using xampp with PHP 5.6.3.

When I'm running with the dev environment, it displays a blank page but whenever I run the app in the prod environment everything works fine.

Here is the php_error_log:

```
[06-May-2015 04:59:03 Europe/Berlin] PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 11 bytes) in C:\xampp\htdocs\Editracker\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\DataCollector\DoctrineDataCollector.php on line 134

[06-May-2015 05:02:38 Europe/Berlin] PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 8192 bytes) in C:\xampp\htdocs\Editracker\app\bootstrap.php.cache on line 956

[06-May-2015 05:06:29 Europe/Berlin] PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 36 bytes) in C:\xampp\htdocs\Editracker\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\DataCollector\DoctrineDataCollector.php on line 176

[06-May-2015 05:06:48 Europe/Berlin] PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 24 bytes) in C:\xampp\htdocs\Editracker\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\DataCollector\DoctrineDataCollector.php on line 176

[06-May-2015 05:11:36 Europe/Berlin] PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 24 bytes) in C:\xampp\htdocs\Editracker\vendor\monolog\monolog\src\Monolog\Formatter\LineFormatter.php on line 111

[06-May-2015 05:34:34 Europe/Berlin] PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 5 bytes) in C:\xampp\htdocs\Editracker\app\bootstrap.php.cache on line 2001

[06-May-2015 05:38:14 Europe/Berlin] PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 36 bytes) in C:\xampp\htdocs\Editracker\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\DataCollector\DoctrineDataCollector.php on line 176
```

What could possibly be wrong?

Comment: Have you deleted your `app/cache/dev` folder as a troubleshooting step?

Comment: yes, I already cleared the cache

Comment: Are you running some huge doctrine query? It could have something to do with logging which you can be disabled using `$em->getconfiguration()->setSQLLogger(null)`.

Comment: yeah, I'm really running a huge query. thanks for this @Qoop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your script is exceeding the max memory allowed. I would suspect this is happening in dev only because of the profiling tools (toolbar at bottom), especially if you have xdebug enabled.

You'll need to increase the memory limit. You can do this in your php.ini file by setting:

memory_limit='256M'

or you can set this in your app_dev.php file if you only want to increase the memory limit in development:

ini_set('memory_limit','256M');

See http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.memory-limit

Comment: I tried setting up the limit higher but it still returns a blank page and still have the same errors in the logs.

Comment: You probably need to restart Apache to pick up the change. You can create a page with phpinfo() to make sure the settings are being applied.

Comment: yes it already worked, thanks but there's another error `PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded` what do you think?

Comment: Ouch, that is a long time. Are you running this code on a computer or a potato? :P. You can increase that too (http://php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-execution-time) but I would only do so temporarily. Need to see what is causing these problems.

Comment: whenever I reset the memory_limit higher, then the execution time gets an error then when i reset the execution time again the memory_limit has again the error. i also tried to the both `memory_limit=-1M` (for no limit, according to web) and `max_execution_time=0`, i don't know what to do anymore

Comment: I dont think you should change either settings, it looks like your code goes into some loop and never comes out of it, or you are performing a calculation which is not getting a value right and throws error. You should debug your code and check if everything is running properly and every value is being assigned, I am sure you will find something and once that is taken care of, your code will run fine without messing around with menory execution time and limit

Comment: At this point I would agree with @Baig. Don't forget to change your setting back when you're done